# create a text file in a folder

Tags: java, file

I want to create a text file into that folder that I am creating here.

```
File dir = new File("crawl_html");  
dir.mkdir(); 
String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(url1.toString());
System.out.println("hash:-"  + hash);
File file = new File(""+dir+"\""+hash+".txt");
```

But this code doesn't create the text file into that folder..Instead it makes the text file outside that folder..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of java.io.File's constructors takes a parent directory. You can do this instead:

```
final File parentDir = new File("crawl_html");
parentDir.mkdir();
final String hash = "abc";
final String fileName = hash + ".txt";
final File file = new File(parentDir, fileName);
file.createNewFile(); // Creates file crawl_html/abc.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

What you need is

```
File file = new File(dir, hash + ".txt");
```

The key here is the [`File(File parent, String child)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) constructor. It creates a file with the specified name under the provided parent directory (provided that directory exists, of course).

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
new File(""+dir+"\""+hash+".txt");
```

makes a file named `crawl_html"the_hash.txt`, because `\"` inside a String literal is used to represent a double quote caracter, not a backslash. `\\` must be used to represent a backslash.

Use the File constructor taking a File (directory) as the first argument, and a file name as a second argument:

```
new File(dir, hash + ".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

your path-delimiter seems off

try:

```
File file = new File ( "" + dir + "/" + hash + ".txt" );
```